# Vue CLI 3 PWA deploying to Production Netlify gives Workbox Error: bad-precaching-response ..._redirects?__WB_REVISION__...404

Tags: vue.js, redirect, progressive-web-apps, netlify, workbox

This issue only happens in production on Netlify. It doesn't present itself in the development environment. 
Usually, I lurk and search to find the answer, or put something together from related answers, but this one has me so stumped...

I've got a Vue CLI project I've had running on Netlify, set up with a PWA that has been running deployed in the past. 
The service worker should be running and the app can be installed for use offline.

Now it's giving me this error in the console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) bad-precaching-response: bad-precaching-response :: [{"url":"https://<domain>/_redirects?__WB_REVISION__=d38a2b58df330c85e0029eecf71d7c26","status":404}]
    at l.o (https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/4.3.1/workbox-precaching.prod.js:1:1749)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async l.install (https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/4.3.1/workbox-precaching.prod.js:1:1221)
```

So it seems to be kicking my '_redirects' file out with a 404 when workbox does it's thing.

I have tried changing the _redirects over to a netlify.toml file with the redirect content in the correct format in the .toml file and it still fails, it's the same error message just with 'netlify.toml' replacing '_redirects' in the error.

I have also tried deploying the same code base to a new Netlify build (thinking it might have been a cache issue with their resources) but the issue persists.

I' guessing that maybe it's an issue with Workbox either failing to compile the assets or giving the wrong name to the files related to redirects. But this also doesn't make sense because they should both be handled by the same code hosted on cdn when I run the build command locally and in the Netlify production environment.

here's the chunk of code that's sending the error from workbox:

```
    const isValidResponse = cacheWillUpdateCallback ?
      // Use a callback if provided. It returns a truthy value if valid.
      cacheWillUpdateCallback({event, request, response}) :
      // Otherwise, default to considering any response status under 400 valid.
      // This includes, by default, considering opaque responses valid.
      response.status < 400;

    // Consider this a failure, leading to the `install` handler failing, if
    // we get back an invalid response.
    if (!isValidResponse) {
      throw new WorkboxError('bad-precaching-response', {
        url,
        status: response.status,
      });
    }
```

Here's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "<app-name>",
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "capacitor-copy": "vue-cli-service capacitor-copy",
    "capacitor-init": "vue-cli-service capacitor-init",
    "capacitor-open": "vue-cli-service capacitor-open",
    "capacitor-update": "vue-cli-service capacitor-update",
    "css:build": "postcss src/css/styles.css -o public/styles.css"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@capacitor/cli": "^1.0.0-alpha.38",
    "@capacitor/core": "^1.0.0-alpha.38",
    "@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss": "^1.3.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.1",
    "core-js": "^3.4.4",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "postcss": "^7.0.26",
    "postcss-cli": "^6.1.3",
    "register-service-worker": "^1.6.2",
    "tailwindcss": "^1.1.4",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-router": "^3.1.3",
    "vue-uuid": "^1.1.1",
    "vuex": "^3.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.2.2",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.2.2",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "^4.2.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "^4.2.2",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "^4.2.2",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.1.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-pwa": "^1.0.0-alpha.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "rules": {},
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions"
  ]
}
```

and my manifest.json file:

```
{
    "short_name": "<name>",
    "name": "<name>",
    "description": "I have no idea what I'm doing with these build tools.",
    "icons": [
        {
            "src": "./img/icons/android-chrome-192x192.png",
            "sizes": "192x192",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "./img/icons/android-chrome-512x512.png",
            "sizes": "512x512",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "./img/icons/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png",
            "sizes": "152x152",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "./img/icons/favicon-16x16.png",
            "sizes": "16x16",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "./img/icons/favicon-32x32.png",
            "sizes": "32x32",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "./img/icons/msapplication-icon-144x144.png",
            "sizes": "144x144",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "./img/icons/safari-pinned-tab.png",
            "sizes": "144x144",
            "type": "image/png"
        }
    ],
    "start_url": ".",
    "background_color": "#2d3748",
    "display": "standalone",
    "scope": "/",
    "theme_color": "#2d3748"
}
```

and the index.html file might help, too:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#2d3748"/>
    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
    <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= BASE_URL %>styles.css">
    <title>NAME</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      <strong>This app doesn't work at all without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  </body>
</html>
```

I don't think it's an issue with my code base, to be honest. I think it will be an issue with configuring the workbox that generates the dynamic URLs when it's deployed to netlfiy. 
As mentioned, the 'npm run build' script has no problem with the build on my local machine.
I'd love to know if anyone has come across this kind of error with netlify or workbox recently.

I'd be very grateful for any assistance.

Answer (score 5):

I've found the issue:
Here's my thinking as I was testing it, was posted elsewhere, too:

I need the _redirects file in the published build directory, but I want to exclude it from the generated manifest that the service worker uses to filter traffic to local or internet assets.
So I’m going to try to specify an exclusion for _redirects

Try:
Change my vue.config.js (a proxy for webpack.config in vue CLI projects) from this:

```
module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        host: 'lite.bdfi.test'
    },
    pwa: {
        name: 'BDFI',
        themeColor: '#2d3748',
        msTileColor: '#2d3748',
        appleMobileWebAppCapable: 'no',
        appleMobileWebAppStatusBarStyle: 'default',
        manifestPath: 'manifest.json',
        workboxPluginMode: 'GenerateSW'
        
    }
}
```

To this:

```
module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        host: 'lite.bdfi.test'
    },
    pwa: {
        name: 'BDFI',
        themeColor: '#2d3748',
        msTileColor: '#2d3748',
        appleMobileWebAppCapable: 'no',
        appleMobileWebAppStatusBarStyle: 'default',
        manifestPath: 'manifest.json',
        workboxPluginMode: 'InjectManifest',
        workboxOptions: {
            // swSrc is required in InjectManifest mode.
            swSrc: 'service-worker.js',
            // ...other Workbox options...
            exclude: [/_redirects/],
        }
    }
}
```

This means that I’m now specifying the input for the service worker, so I need to get a service worker from somewhere.
Here’s my service worker (it’s just a stripped-out version of the autogenerated one)

```
workbox.core.setCacheNameDetails({prefix: "lite-bdfi-app"});

self.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
    
  if (event.data && event.data.type === 'SKIP_WAITING') {
    self.skipWaiting();
  }
});

self.__precacheManifest = [].concat(self.__precacheManifest || []);
workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute(self.__precacheManifest, {});
```

After build it’s the same with the injected manifest and workbox scripts:

```
importScripts("/precache-manifest.54b556dfe16cf1359c2f3257fa76ade9.js", "https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/4.3.1/workbox-sw.js");
```

And also, the local ‘dist’ directory confirms that the ‘_redirects’ file is omitted.

Now I run this build in local and fire it up in the local server, now it’s throwing different errors. in local, which has never happened before…

```
PrecacheController.mjs:194 Uncaught (in promise) bad-precaching-response: bad-precaching-response :: [{"url":"http://127.0.0.1:8887/css/app.159bf243.css.map?__WB_REVISION__=b04e3357da21d1241e39","status":404}]
    at l.o (https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/4.3.1/workbox-precaching.prod.js:1:1749)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async l.install (https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/4.3.1/workbox-precaching.prod.js:1:1221)
n @ WorkboxError.mjs:30
o @ PrecacheController.mjs:194
```

Looks familiar, and there are now 5 of them, all looking for files with a .map extension…
Now I’ll remove .map files from the manifest build and see what that does:

```
workboxOptions: {
            // swSrc is required in InjectManifest mode.
            swSrc: 'service-worker.js',
            // ...other Workbox options...
            exclude: [/\.map$/, /_redirects/], //this fixed it.
        }
```

Run build again, check dist folder manifest, no .map files included in the manifest.
Then check the local version of the app with cleared cache and local storage. no errors there… seems promising.
Push to GitHub. Netlify build triggers, not auto-published, so visit staging link.
No more errors on page load looking for _redirects file.
Check the redirect for ‘/invalid-url’ and it diverts to the 404 pages as intended.
Publishing the deployment, I can now install the app as a PWA on my desktop.

Issue resolved for me.
I hope this helps someone with the same problem in the future.

Comment: It helped me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

only doing this

```
pwa: {
    name: 'App Name',
    workboxOptions: {
        exclude: ['_redirects'],
}
```

works for me.